# Concatenate a word n times

Tags: c, string-concatenation

How can I do something like this?

```
x = abc
x^1 = abc
x^2 = abcabc
x^3 = abcabcabc
```

I tried using the `strcat` function  inside a `for` loop, but it doesn't work.

```c
int potw2;
char w2[100];
w2="abc";
potw2 = 5;
potenciarw2(w2, potw2);
```

---

```c
void potenciarw2(char *pal, int potw2) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < potw2 ; i++) {
        strcat(pal, pal);
    }
    printf("La palabra es:%s\n",pal);       
}
```

Comment: Bad way to use `strcat()`.

Comment: Also, how is `w2` declared?

Comment: Define "it doesn't work". I guess you get what you ask for: powers of 2 increments, instead of *n* times.

Comment: This code should not compile, maybe `char w2[100] = "abc"`?

Comment: Note that `strcat()` requires the source and target strings to be different: the formal C99 prototype is `char *strcat(char * restrict s1,
const char * restrict s2);` and the `restrict` keywords say "the strings shall not overlap" — they must be different.  The C standard also says (for `strcat()` specifically, and also for many other functions): _If copying takes place between
objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `strcat()` for that, I mean for incremental concatenation of a string with known length, I can barely think of a situation where `strcat()` is really useful, there are some situations but generally this would work better, more efficiently for example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *pow_string(const char *const source, int times)
{
    size_t length;
    char *result;
    length = strlen(source);
    result = malloc(length * times + 1);
    if (result == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (int index = 0 ; index < times ; ++index)
        memcpy(result + index * length, source, length);
    result[length * times] = '\0';
    return result;
}

int
input_error()
{
    fprintf(stderr, "error de entrada, ha introducido texto inválido\n");
    return -1;
}

int
main(void)
{
    char *result;
    int power;
    char word[100];
    fprintf(stdout, "Ingrese un texto (máx 99 caracteres) > ");
    if (scanf("%99[^\n]", word) != 1)
        return input_error();
    fprintf(stdout, "Cuántas veces quiere repetir la palabra ? ");
    if (scanf("%d%*[ \t]", &power) != 1)
        return input_error();
    result = pow_string(word, power);
    if (result == NULL)
        return -1;
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", result);
    /* free `result' which was allocated with `malloc()' */
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It can be any value you want if it does not exceed the available ram on your system. Check the update.

Comment: si en esta parte: fprintf(stdout, "Ingrese un texto (máx. 99 caracteres) > "); tengo un arreglo de caracteres no una cadena ,por ejemplo,&caracteres[c] donde c lo define el usuario como podría 'convertir' ese arreglo a una cadena?

Comment: Sorry, I must answer in english. If you want to chat in spanish iharob@gmail.com. I don't understand what you mean. This `&caracteres[c]` would be of type? Perhaps `char caracteres[N]`? If so, `&caracteres[c]` is simple the same array just starting at `c` instead of at the beginning.

Comment: I have per example,&caracteres[0],&caracteres[1],&caracteres[2],how can i put this elements of the array type char named caracteres in this:(scanf("%99[^\n]", word) ?

Comment: You want to `scanf()` multiple words? You should ask a new question then.

Answer (score 4):

`strcat()` expects the destination and source **not** to overlap. In other words, both parameters of `strcat()` cannot point to the same memory.

You need to allocate new memory for the resulting string, and use `memcpy` in a loop.

```
void potenciarw2(char *pal, int potw2)
{
    size_t len = strlen(pal);
    char* result = malloc(len * potw2 + 1); // allocate enough memory for the resulting string and null char
    if (result == NULL) {
        fputs("malloc() ha fallado", stdout);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < potw2 ; i++) {
        memcpy(result + i * len, pal, len); // concatenate string using memcpy
    }

    result[len * potw2] = '\0'; // terminate with null char

    printf("La palabra es:%s\n",result);

    free(result);
}
```

Comment: @iharob The only thing I see that could be called javaish is his indentation style (opening brace on the same line), and that's by no means exclusive to java. I've seen a lot of C and C++ with that style of indentation/braces.

Comment: And C has allowed `//` style comments for a long, long time now. (C99?) Using `/**/` for single-line comments in either language is just silly.

Comment: @CareyGregory Yes sure, this is not a good reason for a discussion. A programmer can use whatever style they want to, if they respect the coding style they use, I mean if it's consistent. It's just my opinion, it might be wrong. Also it's a matter of taste, some people have bad taste and some don't.

Comment: @iharob C99 added support for C++ style comments, so I used that feature. I also prefer using braces around any code block, even if it's a single line.

Comment: @iharob I happen to agree with your taste. I do not like that style of indentation, but it's just style. There's nothing "wrong" about it. When your comment is a single line on a line of code, using `//` is clearer, more concise, and saves horizontal screen space. If `//` won't work, then sure, use `/**/`.

Answer (score 1):

Your function needed a little bit of modification to work. Here's the modification:

```
void potenciarw2(char *pal, int potw2) {

    /* allocate some memory and copy to it*/
    char buffer[100];

    strcpy(buffer,pal);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < potw2 ; i++) {
        strcat(buffer, pal);/*now you can use strcat() safely*/
    }

    /*copy data back to pal*/
    strcpy(pal,buffer);
    printf("La palabra es:%s\n",pal);       
}

int main(void)
{

    int potw2;
    char w2[100] = "abc";
    potw2 = 3;
    potenciarw2(w2, potw2);

}
```

Comment: This code deals with the overlapping memory problem.  It might be better to simply copy the original string into `buffer`, and then repeatedly add the copy to the end of the original string; it saves on the final `strcpy()`.  It suffers (with the original) the lack of information about how big the space available is; it is simply assumed to be 'big enough'.  From the viewpoint of design, the original code is doing two separate jobs in one function: replicating a string and printing a message.  The two jobs should be in wholly separate functions.  However, that's not a problem of your making.